# Inno Setup does not preserve leading zeroes in File Version

Tags: inno-setup, versioninfo

In my Inno Setup I have used

```
#define ver "1.0.0.0001"

VersionInfoVersion={#ver}
```

But my FileVersion (*Application -> Details -> File Version*) gets updated with `1.0.0.1`. I need to show `.0001`.

Please advice

Answer (score 0):

The *"File version"* is stored as four numbers in the standard binary header, not as a string. You cannot choose how it is formatted. That is only possible with *"Product version"*, which is stored as a string.

This is general thing, nothing Inno Setup specific.